# Cannot center DIV

Tags: html, css, center

#### Hi!

This seems like a stupidly simple question, but I cannot seem to horizontally center the header DIV.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ucwafx6/

as you can see, the light blue rounded square is almost centered, but not quite. I've tried on multiple systems, browsers, and screen resolutions and the outcome is always the same. It is slightly further to the right. I really don't understand what is wrong here. I have also tried `margin: 0 auto;` however then it just doesn't do anything and just stays on the very left hand side.

Comment: If you are only targeting more modern browsers you can use flexbox.  See http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox for support.

Comment: Always post your code in your question please. You saw the warning when you posted a link to jsFiddle, yet you chose to ignore it and tried to sidestep it by highlighting couple of words as code. If jsFiddle ever goes away or is inaccessible, then your question loses all value without the code in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's due to the default margin on the body. Just set

`body { margin:0; }`

and you'll see the fix.

Comment: That's a ridiculously easy fix, however it moves the div up a little. Not a problem as I can just extend the margin-top value. Very helpful.

Comment: The reason it moved up is because the top margin is also set to zero.

Comment: Yeah I figured that :)

Answer (score 0):

This should help you center it, assuming you want the position to stay fixed with your current HTML markup.

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6L87r9e1/)

```
#header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #3498db;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  margin-top: 25px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: did exactly what I wanted it to do! It seems ridiculously more complicated then it should be to center a div, but I suppose I've done some things stupidly for it to be necessary. Thanks!

Comment: @Matt rather than using `transform`, `position: fixed` and `left: 50%`, you can use `margin: auto;` to center your div. `margin: auto` will calculate the difference on the left and right and center it for you all in one line of CSS.

Comment: @Press well that should work, yes. But I did try it and it didn't seem to do anything, it just sent the div all the way to the left.

Comment: @Matt The other solution definitely works as well. Make sure to accept the answer that your chose in the end. Cheers.

Comment: @Matt you have to remove the `position: fixed;` for `margin: auto;` to work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the position fixed and set left and right margins to auto and it centers just fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/1ucwafx6/3/

CSS:

```
#header {
    /* position: fixed; */
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #3498db;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 25px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
#header {
    left:0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/1ucwafx6/4/